# Using ttest while increasing samplesize

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, statsmodels

I have a df with different features. I will focous on one feature here, called 'x':

```
count    2152.000000
mean       95.162587
std         0.758480
min        92.882304
25%        94.648659
50%        95.172078
75%        95.648485
max        97.407068
```

I want to perfom a ttest on my df while i sample data out of the df. I want to see the effect of the sampleSize. As i expect it to saturate after a number of samples. Therefore i loop the sampleSize for a specific random_state:

```
for N in np.arange(1,2153,1):
    pull = helioPosition.sample(N,random_state= 140)
    ttest_pull.append(stats.ttest_ind(df['x'],pull['x'])[1])
```

the distribution of 'x' is a normal distribution:

[image: dist 'x']

When i plot the p of the ttest over my sampleSize I get the following plot:

[image: ttest]

Is there a mistake in my code or method. I would expect to get a better p value with a higher sampleSize, but this is not true for every sampleSize. How can a sampleSize of ~1500 be worse than a sample size of ~450?

Answer (score 1):

`pull` is from the sampled from the same data, i.e. the second sample is a random sample from the same population and the two samples have the same mean (expected value).

p-values are uniformly distributed on interval [0, 1] when the null hypothesis is true, which is here the case. This is independent of the sample size, so we expect to see fluctuations or randomness in the p-value of the tests.

However, in this case you do not have two independent samples which is the underlying assumption of the t-test. As far as I understand your code, in the limit as N becomes large the second sample will include the entire "population" and be identical to the first sample. In that case the p-value will go to one because you are comparing two essentially identical samples.

If `sample` samples with replacement, then you are essentially comparing a bootstrap sample with the "population", which would be two samples with the same expected value and very high correlation. So, p-value for standard t-test should be high but still a random number.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer above, what you referring to is power. Basically how many false negative do you have given a certain effect and sample. In your case, the effect is zero since they come from the same distribution, and note you did only one test, which means all your pvalues are basically sampling from a uniform distribution.

What you need is first, a difference between the two distributions, and secondly to perform this test repeatedly to see the number of rejections. See example below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.normal(0,2,150),
                   'y':np.random.normal(1,2,150)})
```

Now we have two columns that have different means. We go through the sampling with different sizes

```
def subsampletest(da,N):
                  pull = da.sample(N)
                  return(ttest_ind(pull['x'],pull['y'])[1])

sampleSize = np.arange(5,150,step=5)

results = np.array([[subsampletest(df,x) for x in sampleSize] for B in range(100)])
```

The number of rejections at alpha of 0.05 (out of 100) per sample size, is simply:

```
rejections = np.mean(results<0.05,axis=0)
sns.lineplot(x=sampleSize,y=rejections)
```

[image]